# Render object as React Component

Tags: reactjs, components, rendering

In my implementation I pass a reactelement (at least that's what I think) as a prop.

I would like to render this prop as it's own React Component but the browser complains that it is an object.

**Code to clarify:**

In parent:

```
render() {
  return <SortableItem {...extraProps} item={React.cloneElement(item, extraProps)} />
}
```

The `item` prop contains the element I want to render in `SortableItem`

**In SortableItem render:**

I want to do something like this:

```
render() {
  return <props.item />
}
```

When I log `props.item` I get this:

```
Object {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), key: "item-5", ref: null, props: 
Object, type: function…}
$$typeof:Symbol(react.element)
key:"item-5"
props:Object
ref:null
type:function _class()
```

I am confused as to why `$$typeof` would say this is a react element indeed, but type says it's a `function _class()` and when I log/render the browser says it's an object.

This is the error I get in the browser when rendering `<props.item />` in `SortableItem`

```
Fatal Exception:Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: 
expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for 
composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of 
`SortableItem`.(reload cancelled)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

**Approach 1**

In parent:

```
render() {
  return <SortableItem {...extraProps} item={<YourComponent />} />
}
```

In SortableItem render:

```
render() {
  return {this.props.item}
}
```

**Approach 2:**
In parent:

```
render() {
  return <SortableItem {...extraProps} >
     <YourComponent />
  </SortableItem>
}
```

In SortableItem render:

```
render() {
  return {this.props.children}
}
```

Comment: Thank you.

How would I turn `React.cloneElement(item, extraProps)` into `<YourComponent />`?

Comment: What exactly are you cloning can you share the code? @skrln

Comment: **In Parent component**
`<ul className={'fc-list-group'}>
          {items.map((item, index) => {
            const extraProps = {
              disabled: !sortable,
              key: 'item-' + index,
              index: index,
            };
            return <SortableItem {...extraProps} item={<{React.cloneElement(item, extraProps)} />} />
          })}
 </ul>`

Where `items` in the map are the original children of this parent component.

I do this because I need some props from this parent (sortable) also on each child along with some extra props (key and index).

Comment: Your Component is something like <li>ABC</li>

Comment: class YourComponent extends Component {
render() {
return <li>abc</li>
}
}

Comment: It works now:

`const SortableItem = (props) => {
  return props.item; //instead of <props.item />
};`

because props.item was in fact already a react element. I got confused trying to make that into a component.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is that every block of logic you manipulate in the virtual DOM needs to be wrapped in a single container element. You can insert and remove a list of components, but they need to be wrapped in a single element. If you return

```
return (
  <div>
    <SortableItem {...extraProps} item={React.cloneElement(item, extraProps)} />
  </div>
)
```

you'll be ok. Vue and Angular have built in template elements for this purpose. I normally make some sort of template component for this purpose in React that is just a div with no margin or padding that can be used to wrap lists of elements.